# Django-FormView and form validation issue

Tags: django

My problem is that even if I put 2 differents password the error message is not showing up, but if I put a password that is less than 6 character the error message appears

[image]

```
class RegistrationForm(forms.Form):
    email = forms.EmailField()
    password = forms.CharField(min_length= 6, widget=forms.PasswordInput())
    confirm_password = forms.CharField(min_length= 6, widget=forms.PasswordInput())
    registration_date = forms.DateField()

    def clean(self):
        password = self.cleaned_data.get('password')
        confirm_password = self.cleaned_data.get('confirm_password')
        if password != confirm_password:
            raise ValidationError("Password error")
```

Here is my view:

```
class Registration(FormView):
   template_name = 'accounts/registration.html'
   form_class = RegistrationForm
   success_url = reverse_lazy('accounts:index')

def form_valid(self, form):
    # my stuff...
```

How can I force to have that sort of "popup" even when the 2 password are different and not only when a password is less than 6 character?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[UPDATE]: Seems like the problem was in the HTML template. All the OP had to do was to put `{{ form.errors }}` in the template in order for the `ValidationError` to show up.

```
def clean(self):
    cleaned_data = super().clean()  # call the super clean() method first

    password = cleaned_data.get('password')
    confirm_password = cleaned_data.get('confirm_password')

    if password and confirm_password:
        if password != confirm_password:
            raise ValidationError("Password error")
```

source: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-and-validating-fields-that-depend-on-each-other

Comment: Please, put a `print` statement before `if` clause and print both `password` and `confirm_password`.

Comment: You should post it in order to figure it out! What the print statement says?

Comment: It print both passwords I've entered as they are

Comment: I've updated my answer. Seems strange that it does not validate. You do put *different* passwords to force the `ValidationError` to appear, right?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to do it. But it doesn't appear, not even with the new solution you proposed

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188498/discussion-between-nik-m-and-tajinder-singh).